# Confusion Matrix return single matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I found an issue with scikit confusion matrix.

I use confusion matrix inside KFold, then when the y_true and y_pred is 100% correct, the confusion matrix return a single number. This make my confusion matrix variable broke, because i add the result from confusion matrix in each fold. Any one have solution for this?

Here is my code

```
model = MultinomialNB()
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
cf = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(x):
    x_train, x_test = x[train_index], x[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
    cf += confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Thank You

Comment: Thats not an issue. Its the desired behaviour when `confusion_matrix` will try to find out the actual classes by itself, based on the data present in y_true and y_pred. See the answer by @Bonlenfum for an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way is probably to pass a list of all possible classes in as the `labels` argument.  Here is an example that shows the issue and it being resolved (based on spoofed data for the truth and predictions).

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix                                      
import numpy as np                                                                

y_test = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0])                                                
y_pred = np.array([0,1,1,1,1,0,0])                                                

labels = np.unique(y_test)                                                        

cf = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])                                                   

for indices in [ [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3] , [1,2,3,4,5,6]]:                             
    cm1= confusion_matrix(y_test[indices], y_pred[indices])                       
    cm2= confusion_matrix(y_test[indices], y_pred[indices], labels=labels)        
    print (cm1.shape == (2,2), cm2.shape == (2,2))
```

In the first subset, both classes appear; but in the second subset, only one class appears and so the cm1 matrix is not of size (2,2) (it comes out as (1,1)).  But note that by indicating all potential classes in `labels`, cm2 is always ok.

If you already know that the labels can only be 0 or 1, you could just assign labels=[0,1], but using `np.unique` will be more robust.

Comment: Perfect. I was just writing this. This is happening due to `KFold()`. Since KFold will just divide the data without taking the class ratio into consideration, this may lead to folds with only a single class in the test data. OP should use StratifiedKFold in these cases as is the standard way in scikit for classification tasks.

Comment: Thank @Bonlenfum you for the explanation, now i understand better about this.

Comment: @Vivek Kumar i dont really understand how StratifiedKFold work, i tried that before, but the data in each fold is not the same, lets say in fold 1 got 8 data, fold 2 got 10 data, etc. So far what i understand is, that StratifiedKFold will divide the data using the same amount of percentage of the class.

Comment: Vivek - yes, stratification is very appropriate and should also resolve this - although I'm not entirely sure how it handles very highly unbalanced classes (e.g. if there are only 9 negative samples and there are 10 folds, it is not possible to ensure unique samples in every fold).

Comment: Widhi - stratification balances the distribution of classes in each fold to match the distribution over the whole training set. See the [docs on stratifiedKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html), "Train and test sizes may be different in each fold, with a difference of at most n_classes".

Comment: Thats a pre-requisite of StratifiedKFold. The minimum number of samples in a class should be equal or greater than the number of splits, else it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can check first if all `pred_values` are all equal to `true_values`. If it is the case, then just increment your `00` and `11` confusion matrix values by the `true_values` (or `pred_values`).

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'f1': [1]*10 + [0]*10,
                  'f2': [3]*10 + [10]*10}).values
y = np.array([1]*10 + [0]*10)
model = MultinomialNB()
kf = KFold(n_splits=5)
cf = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    x_train, x_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
    if all(y_test == y_pred): # if perfect prediction
        cf[0][0] += sum(y_pred == 0) # increment by number of 0 values
        cf[1][1] += sum(y_pred == 1) # increment by number of 1 values
    else:
        cf += confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred) # else add cf values
```

Result of `print(cf)`

```
>> [10  0]
   [0  10]
```

Be careful to ***overfitting***